# Convert object of array to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this

```
[
{"2015":11259750.05},
{"2016":14129456.9}
]
```

and I want to convert this to

```
[
[2015,11259750.05],
[2016,14129456.9]
]
```

is there any function using javascript we can do this.

just to conclude I have a header as well which I want to include with the above result,

```
[
    {"label":"SecuredYear","type":"string"},
    {"label":"ValueInDh‌​s","type":"number"}
]
```

along with above then it should look like `

```
[[
  {"label":"SecuredYear","type":"string"},
  {"label":"ValueInD‌​hs","type":"number"}‌​
], [2015,11259750.05],[2016,14129456.9]
]`
```

thanks

Comment: do you realize the end result you are asking for in a `array of array (multidimentional array)` and not a `object` as you mentioned in the Title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the given array, take the key form the object, make a new array with the data and later unshift the header to the result.

```js
var header = [{ label: "SecuredYear", type: "string" }, { label: "ValueInDh‌​s", type: "number" }],
    data = [{ "2015": 11259750.05 }, { "2016": 14129456.9 }],
    result = data.map(function (o) {
        var k = Object.keys(o)[0];
        return [+k, o[k]];
    });

result.unshift(header);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to generate the array and later add original array at beginning using [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method.

```js
var data = [{
  "2015": 11259750.05
}, {
  "2016": 14129456.9
}];

// iterate over the array to generate new array
var res = data.map(function(v) {
  // get the property name from object
  var k = Object.keys(v)[0];
  // generate element of the array
  return [k, v[k]];
  // if you want to convert property name to number then
  // return [+k, v[k]];
});

// add the original array at beginning
res.unshift(data);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop your array and then extract each object key `Object.keys(obj)[0]` and its value `obj[key]` as shown below.

use [**parseint()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to convert your string data (in your case the object key) into a integer

```js
var data = [{
  "2015": 11259750.05
}, {
  "2016": 14129456.9
}];

var newData = [];

data.forEach(function(obj,index){
   var key= Object.keys(obj)[0];
   newData.push([parseInt(key,10),obj[key]]);
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: but how about converting "2015" to 2015

Comment: Thanks alot it fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad I could help.. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data =[{"2015":11259750.05},{"2016":14129456.9}]
var res=[];

  data.map(function(a){
  Object.keys(a).forEach(function(b){
    res.push([parseInt(b),a[b]])
    })
                
    })
  console.log(res)
```

Comment: @Saleem, please add ths information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it is working as per your expectation :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
{"2015":11259750.05},
{"2016":14129456.9}
];

var newArr = [];
for (var i in jsonObj) {
  var objKeys = Object.keys(jsonObj[i]);
  newArr.push(Object.keys(jsonObj[i]));
  newArr[i].push(jsonObj[i][objKeys[0]]);
}

console.log(newArr);
```